# find files which contains string and append whole contents of that file in new file

Tags: scripting

Can any one help with bash shell script for below requirement?. 
Create one new file called "file.txt" and search for the file containing first line starts with "Format" and put the whole content of that file in new file "file.txt" . This has to be done For all files in current directory so that appended result gets generated in new file.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \
        -exec awk 'NR == 1 && /^Format/ { exit 0 } { exit 1 }' {} \; \
        -exec cat {} \; > /tmp/file.txt
```

This will find all regular files in the current directory and execute the `awk` script on each of them in turn.  Remove the `-maxdepth 1` argument to search recursively.

The `awk` script will exit with a zero exit status if the current file contains the word "Format" at the start of the very first line. If it doesn't, it exits with an exit status of 1.

If the `awk` script exits with a zero exit status, the `find` command will go on to call `cat` with the file which will simply output the contents of it to standard output.

The redirection of `find` to `/tmp/file.txt` will ensure that all files that are outputted by the final `cat` goes to `/tmp/file.txt`.  This file will be truncated (emptied) by the shell before the `find` command starts executing.

You do not want the file `file.txt` to be created in the current directory as that may send the `find` command into an infinite loop.

---

The arguments to `find` used here acts like *tests* on the things that `find` finds.  If a test succeeds, the next test is performed. If one test fails, `find` goes on to look for some other thing.

- The `-maxdepth 1` test fails if `find` finds a directory that would make `find` exceed directory depth 1 if it entered it.  It will therefore only stay on the top-most directory level.
- The `-type f` will fail for anything that is not a regular file (i.e. directories, sockets, device files etc.).
- The `-exec` tests will fail if the command executed returns a non-zero exit status.

Comment: +1. I was working on something very similar to this and looked back to the question to check if i'd missed anything, only to see that you'd beat me to it.   BTW, for @Nirmal's benefit: if the output file needs to be in same dir, either `mv` it later or exclude it with `! -name 'file.txt'` immediately after `-type f`.

Comment: Code looks good, but getting below error....
find: paths must precede expression:  -exec

Comment: @Nirmal I'm assuming that you did not use the _exact_ command that I mentioned. What did the actual command that you tried look like?

Comment: @Nirmal That could happen if you, for example, add `-name file*` or something that expands to multiple names. You need to quote any shell filename globbing patterns used in that way, i.e. `-name "file*"`.

Answer (score 0):

Loop `grep` results:

```
truncate -s 0 file.txt

for match in $(grep -lr "$STRING" --exclude file.txt .); do
    cat "$match" >> file.txt
done
```

`truncate` creates a new file if it doesn't exist or empties existing one.